# PHP Levenshtein for substr search

Tags: php, search, substr, levenshtein-distance

I have a array with strings and need to search that contains some input string. But input can have mistype and contains several words. Search like a google.

Example:

```
$array = ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit", 
          "Praesent elementum mattis risus at condimentum"];
$input = "dolor lrem";
```

1st string is ok. 2nd not.

`levenshtein()` is good for compare mistype strings, but its not suit for `substr` compare.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to calculate strings that match at an accuracy of 40% or greater. [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) will return the number of matching characters in percent for you.

```
$array = ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit", 
"Praesent elementum mattis risus at condimentum","It was popularised","and a search","There are many variations",
"dolor Ipsum is not lrem", "dolor", "lrem", "dolor lrem"];

$text = "dolor lrem";

$strings = array_filter($array, function ($input) use ($text) {
    // Your string accuracy algorithm
    return ((similar_text($text, $input, $percent) * 10) >= 40);
});

print_r($strings);
```

And that will return an array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
[5] => dolor Ipsum is not lrem
[6] => dolor
[7] => lrem
[8] => dolor lrem
)
```

Answer (score 0):

with this function you can compare part of a string with a needle you are looking for while doing a fuzzy matching with levenshtein.

```
"My string where i want to find a part."
"where it want" vs "My string whe"
 "where it want" vs "y string wher"
  "where it want" vs " string where"
   "where it want" ...
    "where it want" ...
     "where it want" ...
      "where it want" ...
       "where it want" ...
        "where it want" ...
         "where it want" vs " where i want"
          "where it want" vs "where i want "
```

you can tune the `$maximalDistance` variable to fit your needs

```
function levensteinSubstringContains($needle, $haystack, $maximalDistance = 2, $caseInsensitive = true)
{
    $lengthNeedle = strlen($needle);
    $lengthHaystack = strlen($haystack);

    if ($caseInsensitive) {
        $needle = strtolower($needle);
        $haystack = strtolower($haystack);
    }

    if ($lengthNeedle > $lengthHaystack) {
        return false;
    }

    if (false !== strpos($haystack, $needle)) {

        return true;
    }

    $i = 0;
    while (($i + $lengthNeedle) <= $lengthHaystack) {
        $comparePart = substr($haystack, $i, $lengthNeedle);

        $levenshteinDistance = levenshtein($needle, $comparePart);
        if ($levenshteinDistance <= $maximalDistance) {

            return true;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return false;
}

foreach ($array as $haystack)
{
    levensteinSubstringContains($input, $haystack)
}
```